# Splitting and cleaning tweets in SQLite file

Tags: python, stream

I am trying to organise streamed tweets in an SQLite file, so the results look cleaner.

However, I am getting, IndexError: list index out of range. So clearly I am doing something wrong with splitting the data, but I just do not know what.

Here is the relevant code. If you need further information then please comment.

```
class listener(StreamListener):

def on_data(self, data):
    #print(data)

    tweet = data.split(',"text":"')[1].split('","source"')[2].split('","created_at"')[3].split('","geo_coordinates"')[4]
    print(tweet)

    saveThis = str(time.time())+'::'+tweet
    saveFile = open('db.sqlite', 'a')
    saveFile.write(saveThis)
    saveFile.write('\n')
    saveFile.close()
    return True

def on_error(self, status):
    print(status)
```

**UPDATE:**

This is an example of a tweet generated without splitting/cleaning.

```
{"created_at":"Sun Dec 02 11:43:26 +0000 2018","id":1069195333006254080,"id_str":"1069195333006254080","text":"AWPS NEWS\nTrump-Xi Meeting Highlights\nand In-Flight Remarks to Press\n -KL Anderson, 12\/2\/2018 **UPDATED\n\nLINK: https:\/\/t.co\/hcIgOFKcdr","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for iPhone\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":708701133951377408,"id_str":"708701133951377408","name":"U(X)=0  'A.I~R.I.S'","screen_name":"UofXis0","location":null,"url":null,"description":"Began with an interest in just A.I. (Artificial Intelligence); now expanding into curiosity about R.I.S. (Robotics and Intelligent Systems).","translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":12,"friends_count":87,"listed_count":3,"favourites_count":0,"statuses_count":588,"created_at":"Sat Mar 12 17:08:12 +0000 2016","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":false,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"F5F8FA","profile_background_image_url":"","profile_background_image_url_https":"","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"1DA1F2","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/708704673746853888\/08z1GxyX_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/708704673746853888\/08z1GxyX_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/708701133951377408\/1457803335","default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"quote_count":0,"reply_count":0,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/hcIgOFKcdr","expanded_url":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/1640346062903605\/posts\/2195483604056512\/","display_url":"facebook.com\/16403460629036\u2026","indices":[111,134]}],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1543751006734"}
```

However, I am trying to only display tweet ID, text, created_at, location, geo_coordinates and followers.

Comment: It should be `data.split(',"text":"')[1].split('","source"')[1].split('","created_at"')[1].split('","geo_coordinates"')[1]` since there'll only be two elements in each split. But that makes no sense, since that's the same thing as `data.split('","geo_coordinates"')[1]`. Looks like you're not wanting to use `.split` in the first place. Do you have an example of input `data` along with the expected output `tweet`? Can you also [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53578863/edit) what it is you're trying to achieve from `data` to `tweet`?

Comment: I tried your method but I am still getting a similar error. I have also updated the post. I hope it is sufficient.

Comment: The tweet looks like JSON. Doesn't Python have a JSON-parsing library/function? Because then you can take advantage of the dictionary data structure, instead of having to rely on string-splitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend converting the record to a dictionary, then you can access all the relevant elements directly without index errors.

Since it is a string, you can:

```
import json
import sqlite3

class listener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(data):
        tweet = json.loads(data)

        # open a database connection to sqlite
        # generally, we would not do this in a function like this
        conn = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite')
        c = conn.cursor()

        # access each element by its key name
        tweet_values = (time.time(), tweet["ID"], tweet["text"], tweet["created_at"], tweet["location"], tweet["geo_coordinates"], tweet["followers"])
        c.execute('INSERT INTO tweets VALUE (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', tweet_values)
        c.close()
```

Comment: Nice. Can you angle this slightly more towards the context of the question? _I am trying to only display tweet ID, text, created_at, location, geo_coordinates and followers._

Comment: I still seems to yield the same results. Could you clarify where I should implement `tweet_dict` and `text`?

Comment: the number of `?` needs to equal the number of values

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Sorry to sound so clueless (I am a newbie), but what do you mean by 'needs to equal the number of values'?

Comment: The number of questions marks in the sql statement should correspond to the number of values in the type within the list of tweet_values

Comment: Unfortunately, I still am not sure what you mean exactly. I am also getting `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: I assumed you had an list of tweets but I see it is a single tweet each time.ideally, the dB creation should be done on `__init__` and not in the `on_data` method